# Jetty 6 from Debain packages with Oracle Java

Tags: jetty, debian

i try to install jetty from the Debian (wheezy) packages. But instead of default Openjdk i installed Oracle Java. 
Download tar.gz. and build a deb package
(https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun or http://www.webstimme.de/2013/02/05/linux-java-unter-debian-wheezy-installieren-anleitung/)

```
$java -v

java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Afterwards i istalled jetty with apt-get, but it also installes the packages

```
openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
```

so Java is then

```
java -version

java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I will give it a second try with installing the Oracle Java version 1.6.
Any Experiences with installing the jetty package repo and use an Oracle Java, will this ever works?

Edit:

It's possible with Oracle Java 6 (1.6) but not with Oracle Java 7 (1.7)

I tried to run it with Oracle Java because of potential better performance for Solr. I somebody has knowledge about the difference in perfomance with Open JDK and Oracle Java it would be nice to post it here :) Thanks

Edit:

I was wrong. It runs also with Oracle JDK 7.
Just download and extract it e.g. to /opt/Oracle_Java and put the path in the /etc/default/jetty as JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/Oracle_Java"
```

Comment: debian really needs to pick up on newer jetty versions, we are releasing jetty 9.1 milestones shortly and fedora is already pushing jetty 9 in their newer versions

Comment: Yeah your right. I can run solr easy without the debian jetty. But i really want to known now if it's possible to run Solr 4.4.0 on Debian Jetty. I have another post about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290177/jetty-6-1-with-solr-4-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run Jetty 6 from Debian or Ubuntu package repository with Oracle Java 6 and Oracle Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Which jre is used by default is controlled by alternatives system. Use the command `update-java-alternatives -l` to list which JREs are installed and then use `update-java-alternatives -s`to choose which JRE to use.

I have two JDKs on my machine:

```
# update-java-alternatives  -l
j2sdk1.6-oracle 315 /usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.6-oracle
jdk-7-oracle-x64 317 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64
```

To use jdk-7 as my default JDK I would run `update-java-alternatives -s jdk-7-oracle-x64`

Comment: Sure i switched between the Java versions with update-java-alternatives. My question was more about the compability of Jetty 6.1 withOracle Java 6 or 7